# magento change default number rows displayed in adminhtml grid pages

Tags: magento, observer-pattern

I would like to set the default number of displayed rows in the admin to higher than 20.
I was following along at http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-admin-grid-how-to-change-number-of-rows/, but I'm trying to make a module to do the task. Magento version is 1.4.2.0.

The error I am getting is `Mage registry key "_singleton/grid/observer" already exists`.

I have in `app/code/local/Company/Custom/etc/config.xml`:

```xml
<config>
  <adminhtml>
    <events>
      <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
        <observers>
          <grid_observer>
            <class>grid/observer</class>
            <method>applyLimitToGrid</method>
          </grid_observer>
        </observers>
      </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
    </events>
  </adminhtml>
</config>
```

and in `app/code/local/Company/Custom/Model/Observer.php`:

```php
class Company_Custom_Grid_Model_Observer
{
    public function applyLimitToGrid(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
        if (($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid) && !($block  instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Grid)) {
            $block->setDefaultLimit(200);
        }
    }
}
```

`app/etc/modules/Company_Custom.xml`:

```xml
<config>
  <modules>
    <Company_Custom>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <active>true</active>
    </Company_Custom>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class Company_Custom_Grid_Model_Observer

should be

class Company_Custom_Model_Observer

Comment: This led me on the right path; the class name was actually wrong in two places...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have module models class declaration:

```xml
<global>
  <models>
    <modulename>
      <class>Namespace_ModuleName_Model</class>
    </modulename>
  </models>
</global>
```

Answer (score 0):

The biggest change was in `Company/Custom/etc/config.xml`, where I put the `<events>` section inside a `<global>` block instead of `<adminhtml>`.

Also inside that file, and fixing the error message was `<class>Company_Custom_Model_Observer</class>` (where I had `grid/observer` before...)